# What's the use of python syntax raise A, L?

Tags: python-2.7, exception, raise

If the following code is called where L is a list, how is L used?

```
raise A, L
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that this syntax is only available in Python 2. Python 3 has [`lib2to3/fixes/fix_raise.py`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2d264235f6e066611b412f7c2e1603866e0f7f1b/Lib/lib2to3/fixes/fix_raise.py)

in its 2-to-3 translation system, which starts with the following docstring, giving you a hint about things the documentation stays silent on (AFAIK):

```
Fixer for 'raise E, V, T'

raise         -> raise
raise E       -> raise E
raise E, V    -> raise E(V)
raise E, V, T -> raise E(V).with_traceback(T)
raise E, None, T -> raise E.with_traceback(T)

raise (((E, E'), E''), E'''), V -> raise E(V)
raise "foo", V, T               -> warns about string exceptions


CAVEATS:
1) "raise E, V" will be incorrectly translated if V is an exception
   instance. The correct Python 3 idiom is

        raise E from V

   but since we can't detect instance-hood by syntax alone and since
   any client code would have to be changed as well, we don't automate
   this.
```

What it boils down to is that `raise FooException, [1, 2]` is equivalent to `raise FooException([1, 2])`; but you should always use the latter.